# Why do I get these strange errors when running PHP scripts?

Tags: php, sqlite

I installed PHP and the SQLite extension using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-sqlite
```

However, each time PHP starts up, I get the message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably worth a bug report.

```
sudo mv /etc/php5/conf.d/sqlite.ini /root
```

See http://acme-tech.net/blog/2011/11/27/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usrlibphp520090626sqlite-so/